# Configure new routing and run DHCP server in router to access internet

Tags: routing, dhcp, nat, subnet, wide-area-network

SO I am a beginner network professional , I was sent to do a routing in client location so they can access the internet .The routing was supposed to be done on cisco 3900 series router. the following info were provided to me.

• WAN V4 address range : 1.2.3.4/30 subnet mask 255.255.255.252
• LAN V4 address range : 5.6.7.8/29 subnet mask 255.255.255.248

• Customer WAN 1.2.3.5
• Tata com WAN 1.2.3.6

The above IP is not the exact IP but it was given in this way ,I calculated the subnets from "/" value and have mentioned above, according to that subnet I got two WAN usable IP one would be configured in ISP router interface and one in my router. and IN the LAN v4 address I got 6 usable IP ,one I assigned to the router interface facing to my LAN and one to my laptop ,I did the default routing to ISP and every thing was up and internet was working. then client came up with request that they want to configure DHCP in router so every device would get IP automatically from 192.168.x.x range as in LAN interface I got 6 usable IP only, we configured the DHCP now the systems are getting IP in 192.168.x.x range but the internet is not up. please suggest how to get the internet up. Is there something to do with natting. Please explain why I did not had to do natting when I used LAN IP given by ISP, and also suggest why the LAN interface IP was given to us as this LAN interface IP is supposed to be added by us according to our will as per my knowledge(correct me if I am wrong I learnt Networking from youtube ). The question is already asked in some platform but was not able to understand, if possible please help me with example.

Comment: and what is the business related question in here? Setting up and or installing a linux/windows dhcp service is a basic process and task for a business administrator. Sorry at the current stage is your question not on topic

Comment: Sir/Mam, please read the question properly its not about configuing DHCP server , the dhcp server needs to be run in router, Which is already done and working, its about accessing internet after getting ip from DHCP and its about why ISP gave 6 usable ip address in lan interface, its about why no natting is required if I am accessing internet if I used one of the 6 ip given by ISP.

Comment: sounds more like a restriction on the router. have you asked the supplier of the router if there is one?

Comment: We are only the supplier of router, We  have reseted the router and there is no restriction.  The DHCP is working fine on the router as the hosts are getting the ip address, I think that we messed up with the natting thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to understand (maybe you do already, but since you mentioned you learned networking from youtube, let's confirm the basics) is that your address example of 192.168.x.x is typical of an *unroutable* 'RFC1918' reserved range for private networks.  This is perfect for the scenario you describe where you may have a bunch of devices on a LAN at a given site where users may consume internet resources but are generally not publishing their own webservers, etc.

Ref:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

Because RFC1918 addresses are non-routable over public internet, yes, you are absolutely going to need either a NAT or proxy-server arrangement to provide a gateway to the internet for these devices to consume internet services. Your average consumer-grade router provided by an ISP with home connection will tend to assume this as standard use-case and configure a source NAT policy so that any device on your LAN that requests content from the public internet will appear "behind" the internet-routable public IP address.

I don't often work with Cisco gear and am not particularly fluent in their configuration CLI but I found an article that looks like it has everything you need to be able to take the information you already have and configure a NAT policy to allow your LAN devices to access internet services, here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_nat/configuration/15-mt/nat-15-mt-book/iadnat-addr-consv.html

(See in particular the paragraph / section titled "Using NAT to Allow Internal Users Access to the Internet")

Good luck and happy networking.....

Comment: Thank you sir for explaining, yes the 192 series I was using was unroutable address which I wanted to use in LAN, so I got to Know that the 5.6.7.8/29 ip they are giving is  not ment for lan interface of router , they are actually public ip's If i want to host any thing, this 5.6.7.8/29 ip got me confused and caused this huge mess.